# Why is it OK to separate a circuit in the process of simplifying it?

Tags: capacitor, dc, inductor

Suppose the switch was closed for a very long time. Why is it ok to separate the circuit like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you think what happens when the switch is closed and will be closed for a long time?

Comment: the capacitor acts as an open circuit and the inductor as a short circuit

Answer (score 1):

Placing a constant voltage source from one node to another isolates (decouples) all branches connected to the nodes from each other.

Because the voltage across each branch is known, each can be analyzed separately.